# Guitar Hero Live controller iOS compatibility

Tags: ps4, ios, guitar-hero-live

Does the Guitar Hero Live controller for PlayStation 4 work with Apple TV/iOS or are they locked to each platform?

Comment: Probably not, but you should look it up too see.

Comment: I'm trying to find this information but it doesn't say on the FAQ on the GH homepage.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://community.guitarhero.com/thread/201193868) the PS4 controller uses a different wireless solution than the iOS controller that uses Bluetooth so unfortunately this will not work.